# During a transition, how do I stop the animated content from overlapping other elements which instantly snap into place?

Tags: html, css

**Explanation**

I found this question a bit hard to word, but the easiest way to see what I'm talking about is by checking out the CodePen that I made.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxqXzL

As you can see, the text content, which is animated, briefly overlaps the `div` below which is instantly moving into the new position. Is there any way I can avoid this?

**CSS**

```
p{
  width:400px;
}

hr{
  width:400px;
  margin-left:0px;
}

.section{
  width:400px;

  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: top;

  &.closed{
    transform: scaleY(0);
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
<hr/>
<p>Text</p>
<hr/>
<div id="section" class="section">
  <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<p>Text</p>
<hr/>
<div class="section">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Without javacript and element detection... **you can't**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed height of your text block you can animate it from `Xpx` to `0px`, if you don't know the height of text, you can do a trick with `max-height:`

example `max-height: 1000px` aniamte to `max-height: 0`;

There can be inconsistency with animation duration between different text blocks, but you can find something middle, which can be hardly noticeable.